# How to type 2 characters on 1 hit with Android custom keyboard

Tags: android, unicode, keyboard

So i'm doing my own Android Keyboard, and I'm doing it with the SoftKeyboard sample.

I'd like to write "ks" with my own key "ks"
So unicode for "k" is 107 and unicode for "s" is 115

```
<Key android:codes="107" android:keyLabel="ks"/>
```

I can't find a way to put  `android:codes="107"+"115"` , a comma is not the solution because if the first or the second letter.

I didn't find either a letter from unicode (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) which is "ks".

Thank you for spending time reading me, I hope there is a solution.

Comment: Have you looked at how e.g. `.com` is sometimes added by a keyboard?

Comment: got it !  android:keyOutputText="ks" I Hope it will help someone:) see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:keyOutputText

Comment: You can post it as an answer (and accept it later on) Laurent, I'll vote up.

Comment: I needed 24h to answer my own question :)

Comment: Yes, and you won't get any points for it, but you will get points for upvotes... It's all in the FAQ and on meta.

Comment: @LaurentRussier Can we achieve same for popover characters..?? Is there any property for that..??

Answer (score 2):

got it ! `android:keyOutputText="ks"` I Hope it will help someone:)
see [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android:keyOutputText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.Key.html#attr_android%3akeyOutputText)